# Source for Chosson & Kallah holding hands after Chuppa

Tags: halacha, wedding

Is there any source for the Chosson & Kallah to hold hands between the Chuppah and the Yichud Room?

Why is this not included in the prohibition of displaying public affection?

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=219

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yekke2. Great to have you learn with us!